# How to persist UI state across configuration change in Android 4.0+

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

My application is to support only landscape content. That content will be generated on-the-fly during runtime, i.e. there will be lots of addView calls to instantiate the UI hierarchy, with some ObjectAnimator calls to move widgets around.
At some point the user might rotate the device to reverseLandscape, insert it in a dock, etc. triggering an activity restart.

Since the appearance on screen should remain the same after the config change I am looking for a lightweight solution to retain the hierarchy.

Adding android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" is discouraged by Google since it does not cover all configuration change cases.

I could create a fragment to contain the UI and call its setRetainState(true) - but again Google discourages that use.

Is there any kind of robust serialization approach to simply write out the current activity state and recreate it once the config change is complete ?